# How does the user's input affect the file and text?

Tags: python, string, variables, text, user-input

In one python file here is the code(It needs to have at least 1 Capital letter and more than 8 letters. If it doesn't then it should ask for the variable password(not username because it doesnt need requirements) until all the requirements have been met. Once the password requirements have been met the username and password should be stored in the text file :

```
reg = open("reg_login.txt", "a")

username = input("Username(Not your real name): \n")
password = input("What is your password?: ")
valid = False
if len(password) >= 8:
    for c in password:
        if c.isupper():
            valid = True
            break
      
reg.write("\n Username = "+username+" Password = "+password)
reg.close()
```

In another file(text file)take the user's input in the first python file and (as an example) it says:

```
 Username = emHilghty Password = sHreoad
 Username = xonnshJ Password = sKshfsadr
```

And in the last file the text file's information must be the same as the user's input in the last file:

```
match = False
while not match:
  user = input("What is your username?: ")
  password = input("What is your password!")

  with open("reg_login.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
      if line.startswith(f'Username = {user},') and line.rstrip().endswith(f'Password = {password}'):
        print('Welcome' , username )
        match = True
        break
     else:
         print("We cannot accept this password")

print(f'Hello {user}.')
```

There are some faults in the 2 python programs. Could you please help me fix them. Thank You!

Comment: "It needs to have..." What is "it"? And what is your question? What does your code do when you run it? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: The main idea of the code is to get user's input from the first python file, store it in a text file and get it to be the same as what the user input's in the last file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what is your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: Making sure that when code is tested it can do all the things in my last statement

Comment: That's still not a question. What specific problems did you encounter? What have you tried, if anything, to solve those problems? What was the result and how did that result differ from what you want? I'd like to help, but I'm not sure what part you need help with.

Comment: I need more details in order to help you. You say "there are some faults" with your code. What are the faults? Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they? If not, what is the output and what do you want it to be instead?

Comment: So when I input on the first file I want the code to match the requirments with the input( 8 letters long or higher and have at least Capital letter). If the requirements are not met then the code should say "we cannot accept this password" and let the user keep on inputting until the user's input meets the requirements. Then the user's input should be stored in the text file. In the last python file the user's input should match what is in the text file. If it doesn't it should say"Incorrect Username or Password" until whatever is in the text file matches the user's input in the last file.

Comment: Please feel free to change some of the code.

Comment: Second Python File :                                                                                                    " if line.startswith(f'Username = {user},') and line.rstrip().endswith(f'Password = {password}'): " I domn't want the user to write " Username = " or  " Password = ". All I want them to write is their username and password so that It can say (" Welcome, " username) and that's the end of the code.

Comment: First Python File : once the requirements have been met the code should say "Thank You" and end there

Comment: Thanks for that description. Now what does your code actually do when you run it? How does this differ from what you want. Note that you should [edit] your question to include both the details you added in comments earlier as well as the additional details I am requesting.

Comment: I have tweaked some of the code. Please feel to tell me what to edit or write the whole code again. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you need help with. You should write the code that checks each of the rules for the password. You can do this with the built in string methods.

Comment: Ok. For the first python file I want the user's input to 8 to 16 letters long and have at least Capital letter. If it does not that then code should say ' We cannot accept this password. Please try again: ' let the user keep on inputting until the user's input has the requirements.

Comment: I recommend implementing each of those requirements one at a time. You already have a good start with `if len(password) >= 8:` to check that the password is at least 8 characters. You can do a similar check to make sure it it less than 16 characters. The only thing left to do is to check that the password has at least one capital letter. It looks like you have some code checking that. Does it work the way you want? If not, what happens? Does it give an error? Or does it give the wrong output?

Comment: 3 minor problems. I don't have the code for making sure the user's input has at least one capital letter. When the user has not met the requirements of the password it should only ask for the password repeatedly and not the username. When the users input doesn't meet the requirements, instead of it going straight to asking the user again for a password. Its should say "We cannot accept this password.\n Enter New Password: " and the user should input after the colon.

Comment: " I don't have the code for making sure the user's input has at least one capital letter." It looks the loop with `if c.isupper():` should do this. Does it not work the way you want? If so, what happens?

Comment: "When the user has not met the requirements of the password it should only ask for the password repeatedly and not the username." You can write a loop that asks for the password and checks if it is valid. If it is not, it repeats and tries again. You can print out whatever message you want when the loop repeats.

Comment: Where do you write the message

Comment: Whenever I try to write the message it interferes with the break command.

Comment: You should write the error message after you check every character in the password. The `break` shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem on the last few lines of the first script.

```
valid = False
if len(password) >= 8:
    for c in password:
        if c.isupper():
            valid = True
            break
```

This part works fine, and it can tell if a password is valid or not. However, you go straight to

```
reg.write("\n Username = "+username+" Password = "+password)
reg.close()
```

without checking if the password is valid. That means that even if the user entered an invalid password, it would still save the username and password to the file.

If you only want to save the file if the password is valid, you could update your program to look like this:

```
reg = open("reg_login.txt", "a")

username = input("Username(Not your real name): \n")
password = input("What is your password?: ")
valid = False
if len(password) >= 8:
    for c in password:
        if c.isupper():
            valid = True
            break
if valid:
    reg.write("\n Username = "+username+" Password = "+password)
    reg.close()
else:
    print("Password is invalid!")
```

In the second script, the line

```
if line.startswith(f'Username = {user},') and line.rstrip().endswith(f'Password = {password}'):
```

matches lines in the format `Username = <username>,<any characters>Password = <password>`. Your first script and the example text file output like this `Username = <username> Password = <password>` (no commas).

Storing data in a flat text file like that is not great practice and can lead to a lot of bugs like this.

You should try investigating something like `pickle` or `json`.

Here's an example of the first script with `json` (it's preinstalled in the standard library, so you don't need to `pip install` it)

```
import json

try:
    with open("reg_login.json", "rt") as reg_file: # Note the .json file extension is not necessary but is recommended:
        reg = json.load(reg_file)
except (json.JSONDecodeError, FileNotFoundError):
    reg = []

username = input("Username(Not your real name): \n")
password = input("What is your password?: ")
valid = False
if len(password) >= 8:
    for c in password:
        if c.isupper():
            valid = True
            break
if valid:
    reg.append({"username": username, "password": password})
    with open("reg_login.json", "wt") as reg_file:
        json.dump(reg, reg_file)
else:
    print("Password is invalid!")
```

I'll leave the second script up to you to write.